# Editar Tabla para cambio de Tipo de Dato

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, datetime

Estaba haciendo unas consultas en una tabla de SQL server, y me he dado cuenta que la fecha, en vez de meterse en DateTime, se metió en char 26. Ahora mismo sale de tal forma:

> 07/07/2022 0:41:42

> 27/07/2022 15:41:42

Mi pregunta es, ¿Puedo editar la tabla para cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna, de char a Datetime, y que lo entienda como una fecha lógica? Es una base de datos que tiene más de 70.000 filas, por lo que la prueba y error me da un poco de respeto.

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Edit1:
Como resumen con la respuesta de las contestaciones de la comunidad, lo he conseguido con la siguiente sentencia:

> ALTER TABLE tabla ALTER COLUMN columna DATETIME

Debería haber hecho un back up e la tabla, pero como tenía una tabla parecida en un SQL que tengo de pruebas, lo hice directamente ahí. Funcionó con la fecha escrita de la forma que puse unas líneas más arriba, y ahora a la hora de comparar fechas funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias a la comunidad, un saludo.

Comment: Hola Jorge un gusto en saludar, siempre puedes hacer una ALTER TABLE a la columna que deseas cambiar el datatype  `ALTER TABLE Persons` , ` ALTER COLUMN date;` tienes que determinar si el datatype **date** o **datetime** te convenga

Comment: Hace un backup de la tabla. SIEMPRE!!!.. luego de eso, te recomendaria crear otra columna con el formato correcto, luego trasladar los datos, y luego borrar la columna que ya no sirve, y en el medio de todos los pasos CHEQUEAR!!! que todo vaya correcto...

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al final utilicé el ALTER TABLE tabla ALTER COLUMN columna DATETIME en un SQL previo que tenía de pruebas, y vi que iba bien, al hacer comparaciones de tiempos ya respondía como debía. Lo que no hice y debería haber hecho, es el back up (miré si podía copiar la tabla como tal, pero al no dejarme, y ver qué sí funcionó previamente, no fui lo sensato que debiera y la alteré). Al final ha ido todo bien, pero me apunto lo del back up y seré más prudente. De nuevo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

ya te han brindado buenos comentarios.
si deseas probar, podrias primero ver que las fechas queden bien al convertirse a datetime. y luego cambiar el tipo de dato.

```sql
drop table if exists #test
create table #test (fecha varchar (26));
insert into #test (fecha) values ('07/07/2022 0:41:42'),('27/07/2022 15:41:42');

select fecha, cast (fecha as datetime) from #test 

--|| luego de verificar rangos de fechas, podrias cambiar el tipo de dato 
alter table #test alter column fecha datetime;

select fecha from #test
```

Comment: Hola @Diego! Hice una cosa parecida y es que tenía un SQL en otro ordenador donde hice directamente las pruebas, y al ver que funcionaba, lo hice directamente en la tabla que me interesaba. Todo bien de momento. Gracias por contestar! soy bastante nuevo en SQL, y hay algún comando de tu creación de tabla y consulta que miraré cómo funciona exactamente. Muchas gracias por pasarte y contestar!

Comment: genial que sirva, abrazo